# I need to update the contents of the dc.identifier.uri metadata for a given collection in DSpace 4.2

Tags: dspace

I migrated a DSpace collection to a new instance, but now I need the source DSpace to assume the identifier generated by the new DSpace instance (domain and identifier).

The procedure must be done in DSpace 4.2.

Any ideas?

**Thank you!**

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. You want to copy the identifiers of the new dpsace, to the old dspace? As far as I know, these problems are solved by the handle system for permanent identifiers. http://www.handle.net/download_hnr.html After migrations remain the same permanent identifiers.

Comment: I created chat room for dspace. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227459/dspace-repository-guide-help-room